# Why does Sitecore redirect with status code 302 for page not found errors?

Tags: redirect

I know that there are solutions for this, and I have written some myself, but what I don't understand is why Sitecore doesn't redirect with 404 OOTB for page not found errors.

Does anyone know if there is a reason why Sitecore <s>doesn't fix this</s> chose to implement it this way and/or if there is any reason why they have patched it?

Comment: `why Sitecore doesn't fix this` - Only Sitecore knows. I can only assume that since this has been in Sitecore for a very long time, at the time it was not considered a SEO _faux pas_.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense too. Thanks @jammykam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it's necessarily a case of that they *won't* fix it, it's just a case of priority. Like all development projects, they'll have a backlog of issues and features that they want to address, and how they go about prioritising them is up to them.

I'm not sure of the original decision behind the 302 redirect, and I can't think of a good reason why it should work like how it does. My honest guess would be that it was just built as a straight-forward redirect as a simple development approach, rather than a conscious decision to not account for correct status values. That is pure speculation on my part though. Though I'm supplying this as answer, someone maybe able to offer more insight here, if there is any to be had.

The best thing to do would be to make sure they're aware of it as something you'd like to see changed. [Raise it on the UserVoice](https://sitecorecommunity.uservoice.com/) and also considering reaching out to support.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't mean to convey frustration, but rather curiosity. I was genuinely wondering if there is a reason why they would redirect to 302 instead of 404

Comment: Don't worry, didn't take it as frustration. I was going to include a bit on that, so I'll edit - though it wont' be too helpful I'm afraid ;)

Comment: Even saying that there is no good answer is an answer for this one ;)